# Why can some words end in either ся or сь? What is the difference?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, non-native-speaker

(Apologies if this question doesn't make sense, I've only been learning Ukrainian for a couple of months.)

I keep seeing words that seem like they can end in either ся or сь and I'm not sure why or what the difference is.  For example [wictionary lists залишитися](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F) (if you open the conjugation table) as having three infinitive forms, "залиши́тися, залиши́тись, залиши́ться" - and then most of the conjugations have two or occasionally three forms but some only have one. What's going on with that? Is it a local dialect variation, or are the meanings different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is the difference?**

Only one: *залиши́тися* is a standard dictionary form for the infinitive. So, if you search the word in a dictionary then choose only with *-ти(ся)* like this.

**Is it a local dialect variation?**

If you're speaking about things such tests and exams, then there is a standard orthography:

> [**§ 115. Indicative**](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=120)
>
> **Rule #9.** *[…]*
>
> **Note #3**: Itʼs always a postfix **-ся**. But in talking, or [writing style](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writing_style) you can also use **-сь**. But if itʼs past time for masculine then *-сь* can be only after *в*: *усміхну́всь* (but *стері́гся*).

> [**§ 118. Infinitive**](//mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=122)
>
> Infinitives end with **-ти**: *[…]*.
>
> **Note #1**: In talking, or writing style you can also use **-ть** if a base (a part before *-ти*) of a word ends with vowel: *[…]*.

But itʼs kinda *yes*, because some dialects prefer *-ти*, and others prefer *-ть*. The standard language is a mix of dialects; therefore you can use what you prefer. But of course, a dictionary form is the most popular.

If speak about dialects then you can also [notice](//r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovozmina_diyeslovo) many things, for example some of them:

- for *he/she/it* removing *-ть*: [він] *залише(ся)*, or [adding](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F) *-ть*: *несеть* instead current standard *несе*,
- *ся* can be separated from verb: *ся залишити*;
- *ся* can be writed also as [*си*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%B8);
- *ть* can be writed also as just *-т*: *залишит*.

**Whatʼs going on with that?**

Well… itʼs not so simple but letʼs try.

In some cases itʼs [mixing](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BD#%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BD_%D1%83_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) between [supin](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supine#Slavic_languages) and infinitive.

But mostly itʼs just phonology where:

- removing a vowel but saving palatalizing for consonant: *ся* − *а* → *сь* [*я* = *ьа*], *ти* − *и* → *ть* (historicaly *и = ьi* here) etc; for note, it happens in [imperative](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1) too: [*крадь*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) or *кради*;
- in some cases removing palatalizing: *ть* → *т*;
- in some cases *и* [read *ьi*] becoming as [today *и*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98#%D0%A3_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96).

**Another note**

By a rule of [orthoepy](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)#%D0%97%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) a part *тьсь* like in *ться* is read as long *ць*, therefore *залишиться* is *залишицця* by pronounce.